# Error In FileUpload asp.net Using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

i Use This Code For File Upload But NotWorking

Default.aspx Code

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <h3>FileUpload.SaveAs Method Example</h3>

    <form id="Form1" runat="server">

        <h4>Select a file to upload:</h4>

        <asp:FileUpload id="FileUpload1"                 
            runat="server">
        </asp:FileUpload>

        <br /><br />

        <asp:Button id="UploadButton" 
            Text="Upload file"
            OnClick="UploadButton_Click"
            runat="server">
        </asp:Button>      

        <hr />

        <asp:Label id="UploadStatusLabel"
            runat="server">
        </asp:Label>   

    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

And This IS a Default.aspx.cs Code

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void UploadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Before attempting to save the file, verify
        // that the FileUpload control contains a file.
        if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
            // Call a helper method routine to save the file.
            SaveFile(FileUpload1.PostedFile);
        else
            // Notify the user that a file was not uploaded.
            UploadStatusLabel.Text = "You did not specify a file to upload.";
    }

    void SaveFile(HttpPostedFile file)
    {
        // Specify the path to save the uploaded file to.
        string savePath = "~/Uploads/";

        // Get the name of the file to upload.
        string fileName = FileUpload1.FileName;

        // Create the path and file name to check for duplicates.
        string pathToCheck = savePath + fileName;

        // Create a temporary file name to use for checking duplicates.
        string tempfileName = "";

        // Check to see if a file already exists with the
        // same name as the file to upload.        
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(pathToCheck))
        {
            int counter = 2;
            while (System.IO.File.Exists(pathToCheck))
            {
                // if a file with this name already exists,
                // prefix the filename with a number.
                tempfileName = counter.ToString() + fileName;
                pathToCheck = savePath + tempfileName;
                counter++;
            }

            fileName = tempfileName;

            // Notify the user that the file name was changed.
            UploadStatusLabel.Text = "A file with the same name already exists." +
                "<br />Your file was saved as " + fileName;
        }
        else
        {
            // Notify the user that the file was saved successfully.
            UploadStatusLabel.Text = "Your file was uploaded successfully.";
        }

        // Append the name of the file to upload to the path.
        savePath += fileName;

        // Call the SaveAs method to save the uploaded
        // file to the specified directory.
        FileUpload1.SaveAs(savePath);
    }
}
```

And This Error Shows Me When I Run It

An exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code

And What am I Doing to fix This?
Thanks

Comment: please check your path you use to save the uploaded file.I think there must be a problem in your savePath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this simple code hope will helpfull to you for uploading an image

```
 string _fname,_fpath;
                if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
                {
                   _fname = FileUpload1.FileName.ToString();
                   _fpath="~/upload/"+_fname.ToString();
                    FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/upload/") + _fname);
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into tablename(Name,Image) values('" + TextBox1.Text + "','" + _fpath + "')", con);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    try
                    {
                        con.Open();
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        Label1.Text = "Data inserted successfully";
                        con.Close();
                        TextBox1.Text = "";
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Label1.Text = ex.Message;
                    }
                }
```